# replace domain name in htaccess rule with dynamic hostname

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I Have this rule in `.htaccess`:

```
1 ## Protect from spam bots ##
2 RewriteEngine On
3 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
4 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .wp-comments-post\.php*
5 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !.EXAMPLE.COM.* [OR]
6 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
7 RewriteRule (.*) ^http://%{REMOTE_ADDR}/$ [R=301,L]
```

I want to replace the **EXAMPLE.COM** at line 5 with the dynamic hostname.
I would like to use the same rule with other domain without having to modify `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !.DOMAIN.COM.* [OR]
> ```

The complexity comes about because server variables of the form `%{HTTP_HOST}` are not expanded in the *CondPattern* (2nd argument to the `RewriteCond` directive), since it is a *PCRE* (regular expression).

Instead of the above line, you can do something like this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^(.*?)@@https?://\1/ [OR]
```

This checks that the requested `Host` header matches the *hostname* part of the HTTP `Referer` header.

The `\1` backreference (in the Referer) matches against the Host. The `@@` string is just any unique string that cannot otherwise occur.

Note that it is possible for legitimate users to not send an HTTP `Referer` header at all, in which case your current ruleset will also *fail*.

> ```
> RewriteRule (.*) ^http://%{REMOTE_ADDR}/$ [R=301,L]
> ```

Note that the *substitution* string in your `RewriteRule` is malformed. It is an "ordinary" string, not a regex. Consequently, the anchors `^` and `$` will be seen as literal characters and should be removed:

```
RewriteRule .* http://%{REMOTE_ADDR}/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: How did you get on with this? If this answered your question then please mark it as accepted (checkmark below the voting arrows on the left) to remove it from the unanswered question queue. Thanks, much appreciated. :)

Comment: Ok @MrWhite thanks a lot!
I have a question, this rule will work with **https** site?

Comment: Yes, it will work with both HTTP and HTTP Referers. The `?` in the regex `https?://` makes the preceding `s` optional. If your site is _only_ HTTPS then you can remove the `?`.